# How to disable Javascript action on links (<a>) on Bootsrap3 non-real-links (<a href="#..."/>)?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have an `<a>` tag on my website, a script which shows a loader when you click on a link (any links).

Here is the code :

```
window.onload = function(){
  var loading = document.getElementById("loading");
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll("a");

  function showLoading(){
      loading.style.display = "block";
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
      elements[i].addEventListener("click",showLoading);
  }
}
```

Problem: on non-real links `<a href="">`, like "tabs" or "dropdown" on Bootstrap3, the load is still running. How can I avoid this ? (using a general `.class` or like this ?)

Comment: Well, why not use a seperate class for this? As you've already suggested to do that, why not try and see what happens?

Comment: Because it's not my code, i'm a Rails back-end dev with no skills in Javascript... :'(

Answer (score 0):

According to [Bootstrap v4 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/dropdowns/#menu-items) you can now use buttons instead of links, like this:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could specify `let elements = document.querySelectorAll("a:not(.class-all-inactive-links-share"))`.

Comment: Thanks for answere Jordan. We still are with Bootstrap3, it should work the same..? Where we should add you code line ? Non skilled on js, sorry...

Comment: Unfortunately, with Bootstrap v3 the dropdowns have to be links--they cannot be buttons. It is a new feature of v4. The link I provided above points to examples of using buttons instead of links, but again, that's v4 only.

Answer (score 0):

What about disabling those anchor tags using this jquery?

```
$('#anchor_tag').attr("disabled", true);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, can you pls edit with the code ? I'm not skilled at all in js...